# Truetype or Opentype for custom web font?

Tags: fonts, opentype, truetype, eot

We plan on purchasing a font but we are unsure what format to get it in.  We use both Macs and PCs in the office but we also want to make sure it works when we use the @font-face CSS code.  I do use a program that converts it to an eot also.

Answer (score 1):

But what's the actual question? If you want advice on which to buy: buy the one the foundry says is better, and make sure you buy it as a typeface, not as "a font file". You buy a license to use the typeface, with a license to use it as a webfont, and then you can use whatever actual format you need for online deployment. For modern browsers, that means .wOFF (which is just an opentype font, wrapped as a wOFF binary).

Also note that modern TrueType fonts **are** OpenType fonts. The font is an OpenType font, either with TrueType outlines and associated tables, or with Type2 outlines and associated CFF table.

Bottom line: wrong question; you want to get the typeface in a format that best suits it, and a license that lets you deploy it online in whatever format(s) is/are necessary to support the browsers you need to target.